# Circular template reference structure

Tags: c++, templates, structure, cyclic-reference

I have a ploblem about circular template reference. I want to make a tree using class node and class edge as following;

```
template <typename EdgeT>
class node
{
public:
    std::vector<EdgeT> edge_out;
    std::vector<EdgeT> edge_in;
};


template <typename NodeT>
class edge
{
public:
    NodeT* src;
    NodeT* dst;
    int weight;
};


template <typename NodeT, typename EdgeT>
class graph
{
public:
    std::vector<NodeT> nodes;
};
```

I found that I cannot declare graph class ex:

```
graph< node, edge > g; // <--- this cannot be solved 

graph< node< edge <node.....>, edge< node< edge>>  >  //it makes infinity declaration..
```

How can I redefine the structure of the classes?

Comment: Does it have to be templated?

Comment: "edge" and "node" class there should be  the base classes. I plan to reuse them. ex an inherited edge can contain "flow" "reverse_flow" ....  or an inherited "node" class can has more data such as flag, ..etc...  so thats why i make them as templates

Comment: this isn't making any sense to me... how can a node hold an edge with a source and a destination? Isn't the source always the node itself? It should be holding a list of nodes...

Comment: I treat "edge" as a pipe. when you pick up an edge, you should know where it is link to (pointer to node). And "node" as the container of "edges".

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach:

```
#include <vector>

template<template<typename NodeT,typename T>class EdgeT, typename T=double>
struct Node {
   typedef Node<EdgeT,T> self_type;
   typedef EdgeT<self_type, T> edge_type;
   std::vector<edge_type> edge_out;
   std::vector<edge_type> edge_in;
   T data;
};

template<typename NodeT,typename T>
struct Edge {
   typedef NodeT node_type;
   node_type* src;
   node_type* dst;
   int weight;
};

template<typename NodeT, typename EdgeT=typename NodeT::edge_type>
struct graph {
   typedef NodeT node_type;
   typedef EdgeT edge_type;
   std::vector<NodeT> nodes;
};

int main() {
   typedef graph< Node<Edge> > graph_type;
   graph_type my_graph;
   my_graph.nodes.push_back( graph_type::node_type() );
   my_graph.nodes.push_back( graph_type::node_type() );
   my_graph.nodes.front().edge_out.push_back( {&my_graph.nodes[0], &my_graph.nodes[1], 1} );
   my_graph.nodes.back().edge_in.push_back( {&my_graph.nodes[0], &my_graph.nodes[1], 1} );
}
```

for another approach, you could look at how `boost::variant` handles recursive variants.

Another way to approach this would be more formal.  C++ template metaprogramming is a functional language -- there are various techniques from functional programming in order to describe recursive structures without forward declaration that can be used.

I'm betting a fixed point combinator of some kind might work, but it is beyond me to figure out how.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out the reason why you need to use templates. If for example you want to have the data dynamic in an edge, you could use:

```
//foward declaration
template <typename T>
class node
{
std::vector<Edge<T> > edge_out;
std::vector<Edge<T> > edge_in; 
} 


template <typename T>
class edge
{
Node<T>* src;
Node<T>* dst;
T    weight
}


template <typename T>
class graph
{
std::vector<Node<T> > nodes;
}
```

Likewise if you want to have data that differs in your node. But in general it is better to figure out the reason for templates beforehand. I have looked at overly templatized production code and it is quite unmaintainable.